# Proof without using the proof of contradiction

Tags: prime-numbers

By using the proof by contradiction I can determine that the root of a prime number is irrational. 
But how can I proof this by using the rational roots test to find rational factors of $x^n - p$. How does this information leads me to get a proof?

$p=$ prime number,   $n > 1$ (integer)

Comment: Why don't you add a description of this "rational roots test" to your question?

Comment: "Rational root test" is defined by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and a lot of other sources to be the Rational root theorem.